# python injection protection for multiple column queries

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, sql-injection

how would I do secure sql injection in the following code?  normally i would use a comma instead of the percent sign, because it doesn't directly inject a string, but I cant do that when i want to select multiple columns from the database.

this works but is not safe:

```
def (columns)
    % columns is string of column names separated by commas
    id = 5
    queryStr = """SELECT %s FROM dash WHERE id=%s LIMIT 1"""
    q.execute(queryStr % (columns, id))
```

while this doesn't work:

```
def (columns)
    % columns is string of column names separated by commas
    id = 5
    queryStr = """SELECT %s FROM dash WHERE id=%s LIMIT 1"""
    q.execute(queryStr, (columns, id))
```

I need to be able to change the amount of columns Im searching for when I call this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `params` argument of `execute()` to add columns to the query anyway, because that will add single-quotes around the argument, which will force it to be treated as a string. You'll end up with this query:

```
SELECT 'item1, item2, item3' FROM dash WHERE id=5 LIMIT 1
```

You have to interpolate the columns yourself.

To protect against SQL injection, it's your responsibility to filter the list of column names and validate it against a list of known columns of this table. Consider this a *whitelisting* process.

Comment: yeah, that is the result I have been getting so far.  I understand the answer you gave, however the method this is from needs to select a different number of columns from the table most of the time it is called.  is there any way to vary the number of columns called in the query and which columns are called by the query using variables?